'imports' is only valid on a component that is standalone
I updated my Angular 18 applications (with standalone components standalone: true) to Angular 19 using ng update:
❯ Updates non-standalone Directives, Component and Pipes to 'standalone:false' 
  and removes 'standalone:true' from those who are standalone.

So far so good, all standalone: true are removed.
However, Visual Studio Code is now issuing following error for imports: [RouterLink, ...]:
'imports' is only valid on a component that is standalone.

What did I miss?
I followed this guide:

https://angular.dev/update-guide?v=18.0-19.0



Restarting VS Code, solved the problem as per Thomas. If not try the below suggestion.

Could you try upgrading the angular language service plugin to the latest version and check if the issue is fixed.

Angular Language Service was already updated (and as well reloaded). However, your hint made me restart Visual Studio Code and the issue is gone. Thank you for your help!

The problem lies in the package.json file of @angular/language-server at line 18: "@angular/language-service": "19.0.0-next.6". The version should be 19.0.0, because in version 19.0.0-next.6, the variable isStandalone is set to false by default.
Method 1:
To resolve this, you can modify the package.json file inside @angular/language-server and set the version to 19.0.0. After doing this, delete the @angular/language-service folder and the package-lock.json file, then run npm install. Ensure that your package.json file inside @angular/language-service contains the line "version": "19.0.0".
Method 2:
Inside the file @angular/language-service/bundles/language-service.js, the variable isStandalone is initialized as false. Change all lines from:
let isStandalone = false;

to:
let isStandalone = true;


Either restarting VS Code, updating angular language service as mentionened here,
but if that doesn't solve the issue and you have a workspace containing multiple different angular projects, try to make a clean workspace containing only v19 projects.
